# How to display range of values using h5dump on terminal

Tags: bash, hdf5, h5py, hdf

I am trying to print the range of values using `h5dump` command.

My dataset is 3-dimensional data (X-axis, Y-axis and Z-axis), assume I want to print the display all the data values of a particular X-axis.

Below is the command that I executed:

```
h5dump -d X --start="2"  file.hdf5
```

Results:

```
HDF5 "file.hdf5" {
DATASET "X" {
   DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F32LE
   DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 10, 10, 10 ) / ( 10, 10, 10 ) }
   SUBSET {
      START ( 2, 0, 0 );
      STRIDE ( 1, 1, 1 );
      COUNT ( 1, 1, 1 );
      BLOCK ( 1, 1, 1 );
      DATA {
      (2,0,0): -0.443565
      }
   }
}
}
```

I tried using the `count` argument as:

```
h5dump -d X --start="2" --count="10,10" file.hdf5
```

Results:

```
HDF5 "file.hdf5" {
DATASET "X" {
   DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F32LE
   DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 10, 10, 10 ) / ( 10, 10, 10 ) }
   SUBSET {
      START ( 2, 0, 0 );
      STRIDE ( 1, 1, 1 );
      COUNT ( 10, 10, 0 );
      BLOCK ( 1, 1, 1 );
      DATA {
      }
   }
}
}
```

But it doesn't display any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by providing the `count` attribute in 3-dimensional format as below:

```
h5dump -d X --start="2" --count="1,10,10" file.hdf5
```

Resulting:

```
HDF5 "file.hdf5" {
DATASET "X" {
   DATATYPE  H5T_IEEE_F32LE
   DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 10, 10, 10 ) / ( 10, 10, 10 ) }
   SUBSET {
      START ( 2, 0, 0 );
      STRIDE ( 1, 1, 1 );
      COUNT ( 1, 10, 10 );
      BLOCK ( 1, 1, 1 );
      DATA {
      (2,0,0): -0.443565, 0.093538, -0.046598, -0.390718, -0.40143, -0.75803,
      (2,0,6): 0.200715, 0.717508, 0.449602, -0.027501,
      (2,1,0): 0.633949, 0.010584, 0.211322, -0.268771, -0.287361, -0.022143,
      (2,1,6): -0.078199, 0.125665, 0.143302, -0.337159,
      (2,2,0): -0.579271, -0.079719, -0.402029, 0.017853, 0.057314, 0.741759,
      (2,2,6): -0.159521, -0.002631, 0.465817, 0.106915,
      (2,3,0): 0.173458, 0.261899, 0.244239, -0.057464, 0.638488, 0.406673,
      (2,3,6): 0.057691, 0.220089, 0.31774, -0.044191,
      (2,4,0): -0.307582, -0.51839, 0.407623, -0.023077, 0.598121, 0.076373,
      (2,4,6): 0.213476, 0.629848, 0.199875, -0.55026,
      (2,5,0): 0.272402, 0.141062, -0.445451, 0.154252, 0.512982, 0.296819,
      (2,5,6): 0.394003, 0.195487, -0.381298, 0.233568,
      (2,6,0): 0.250801, 0.648142, 0.129092, -0.277806, -0.327215, 0.592183,
      (2,6,6): 0.070691, 0.173107, -0.689989, 0.075781,
      (2,7,0): 0.1983, -0.101234, -0.256516, -0.074656, -0.254037, -0.131074,
      (2,7,6): 0.169034, 0.636948, -0.745117, 0.026536,
      (2,8,0): 0.400796, 0.236168, -0.791067, -0.360954, -0.423373, 0.063263,
      (2,8,6): 0.533191, 0.795309, 0.183088, -0.522514,
      (2,9,0): 0.924088, 0.740839, -0.027343, -0.659531, 0.496281, 0.639562,
      (2,9,6): 0.116791, 0.802226, 1.0194, -0.825602
      }
   }
}
}
```